# Does correlation between variables changes if they are scaled by a constant?

Tags: correlation

I may sound blunt, sorry in advance. I have read a statement that  **"If X and Y correlate, then X/Z and Y/Z may correlate more even if Z happens to be random"**. I tried this numerically but I couldn't find any difference in correlation after scaling both X, Y by a constant. So is this statement wrong?

Comment: "Z happens to be random" suggests (although the wording is very vague) that Z is a *random variable*, not a constant. If Z is indeed a constant then @David's answer below ("yes, the correlation remains the same") is correct.

Comment: I think my interpretation was wrong. Z can be a vector of random variables, say Sales quantities. Assume X is a vector of Profit figures and Y is a vector of, say, total expenses; then the statement I wrote means the correlation between Profit(X) & total expenses(Y) will be different when the same variables are scaled by Sales in $(Z). Am I right?

Comment: Hint: work the question backwards by starting with two perfectly correlated variables $U$ and $V$ (which means almost surely $V=aU+b$ for *constants* $a\ne 0$ and $b$).  Pick any non-constant, non-zero variable $Z$ and define $X=ZU$ and $Y=ZV.$ Because $Z$ varies, $X$ and $Y$ will not be perfectly correlated.  What can you conclude from this example? Try it by making up a small dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Correlation is invariant to scale (or, for that matter, any other linear transofrmation). That's one of its main "advantages" relative to [covariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance)

For the "divide by $Z$ case", I don't really know the true insights, but you can try the following R code:

```
set.seed(42)
x=2+rnorm(10000,sd=0.1)
y=2*x+1+rnorm(10000, sd=0.1)
cor(x,y)
z=rnorm(10000)
```

`cor(x,y)` returns something about .89 while `cor(x/z, y/z)` returns something more like .99994

Comment: The above means scaling may Increase the correlation,right?

Comment: No. By scaling we mean multiplying/dividing by a constant. Multiplying by a random variable is a very different thing, and that can indeed mess wth correlation